# Radio buttons are not working in Native-Base

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am using Native-Base. I need to use radio buttons, but they don't work. When you click nothing happens. Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, ListItem, Text, Radio, Right } from 'native-base';
export default class RadioButtonExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <ListItem>
            <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={false} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <Text>Discussion with Client</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={true} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I make it work? Please don't send different libraries which are containing just radio button functionality. I already checked different radio button libraries. Just need to add something to this code for making it work.

Answer (score 13):

you can add `onPress` as it replacement of [TouchableOpacity](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) it will accept it's props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, ListItem, Text, Radio, Right } from 'native-base';
export default class RadioButtonExample extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   itemSelected: 'itemOne',
 }
}
render() {
 return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
          <Right>
            <Radio onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: 'itemOne' })}
              selected={this.state.itemSelected == 'itemOne'}
            />
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>Discussion with Client</Text>
          <Right>
            <Radio onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: 'itemTwo' })}
                  selected={this.state.itemSelected == 'itemTwo' }
                />
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
      </Content>
    </Container>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: it shows syntax error but doesn't show whats the exact error.

Comment: Must I duplicate code for radio twice? I have 2 radio buttons. and when you select first one second one must be turned off.  I changed this.state true in the constructor  it was turned on and when I click  one of them both have been turned off, but after that when you try to select again nothing happens

Comment: still not working :( first one is selected and when I click to second one nothing happens while first one must be turned off and second one turned on.

Comment: And it works for you?I  added it but issue the same 2nd button is not working.

Comment: Yes, and I used the last version but still second radio is not working :(

Comment: I already tested this are you want all the list item clickable or just the radio also are you sure that nothing else overlapping your radio button?

Comment: Yes I am sure. In this code by default first radio is turned on. when you click on the second radio (not text) nothing happens, there is already first one turned on.

Comment: I am not sure try to copy paste my full code i tried it and it is working with me so there is two things may be you doing wrong first you misspell some thing second some thing is overlapping your second radio

Comment: I checked it on android worked, but on iOS nothing happened.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest an easy way is, first create an array of radio items.

```
const radioItem = [
    { label: 'Female', value: 'female' },
    { label: 'Male', value: 'male' }
];
```

Then inside your content do it like this.

```
<Content>
   <Text>Select your choice</Text>
   {
     radioItem.map((data, key) => {
         return (
                  <ListItem key={key}>

                     <Left>
                         <Text>{data.label}</Text>
                     </Left>
                     <Right>
                         <Radio
                            onPress={()=> this.setState({radioValue:data.value})}
                            color={"gray"}
                            selectedColor={"gray"}
                            selected={data.value === this.state.radioValue}
                          />
                     </Right>
                  </ListItem>
                 )
       })
   }
</Content>
```

Let's understand this:

First you need to understand about the Radio component of native base it use selected props to check Boolean value true or false and accordingly it shows the active radio.

So, we are using onPress action to get the current value and we are storing it to the state and our selected props matches for the value and returns true or false.
So we can see by default our value will be false for both the radio item as we don't have the state value.

You can also set the default selected radio by defining the state value inside the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The `onPress` property must be on the ListItem node.
I managed to make it work by doing this:

```
                <ListItem
                    selected={this.state.registerForm.type == 'item1'}
                    onPress={() => this._handleRegisterFormChanges('item1', 'type')}
                >
                    <Left>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                            <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>Radio text 1</Text>
                        </View>
                    </Left>
                    <Right>
                        <Radio
                            selected={this.state.registerForm.type == 'item1'}
                            color={Colors.tintColor}
                            selectedColor={Colors.tintColor}
                        />
                    </Right>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    selected={this.state.registerForm.type == 'item2'}
                    onPress={() => this._handleRegisterFormChanges('item2', 'type')}
                >
                    <Left>
                        <View >
                            <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>Radio text 2</Text>
                        </View>
                    </Left>
                    <Right>
                        <Radio
                            selected={this.state.registerForm.type == 'item2'}
                            color={Colors.tintColor}
                            selectedColor={Colors.tintColor}
                        />
                    </Right>
                </ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the RadioGroup to redux-form, this is the code with horizontal radio layout:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Radio, View, Text, Label } from 'native-base';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { required } from './validaciones';

const RadioGroup = ({ label, name, options }) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {!!label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
    <View style={styles.radioContainar}>
      <Field
        validate={[required]}
        component={({ input, options }) => options.map(option => (
          <View key={option.id} style={styles.radio}>
            <Radio
              id={option.id}
              type="radio"
              {...input}
              value={option.value}
              onPress={() => input.onChange(option.value)}
              selected={option.value === input.value}
            />
            <Text onPress={() => input.onChange(option.value)} style={styles.label}>
              {option.label}
            </Text>
          </View>
        ))
        }
        name={name}
        options={options}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);

RadioGroup.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  ),
  label: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 14,
    marginBottom: 7
  },
  radioContainar: {
    marginTop: 7,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  },
  label: {
    marginLeft: 3
  },
  radio: {
    marginRight: 14,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  }
});

export default RadioGroup;
```

Usage:

```
<RadioGroup
  label="Sexo"
  name="sexo"
  options={[
    {
      id: 'gender-male',
      label: 'Hombre',
      value: 'HOMBRE'
    },
    {
      id: 'gender-female',
      label: 'Mujer',
      value: 'MUJER'
    }
  ]}
/>
```